# Python3 requests get content

Tags: html, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to get an html content but it seems that I can't get all of it with python.
When you browse the url (https://www.1999.co.jp/eng/10571339) there is a content which seems to be automatically translated to English. Anyway by looking the source on the browser I can find the text "This item is limited to 3 per household."
By doing a str(request.get(url).content) this sentence doesn't exists.
Is there any reason? How can I find the reason?

Comment: `request.get(url)` does not execute any JavaScript. That's the reason.

Comment: I see so "Ajax" loading... Is there a way to get the content provided by the execution of JS?

Comment: Yes. Read about Selenium and about Chromedriver.

Comment: Wait this worked for me and I was able to find `"This item is limited to 3 per household."` Can you check again.

Comment: @Aashutosh Rathi I tried again and same.

Comment: @Tomalak Sadly I need to use python only so that's a showstopper to do the feature :(

Comment: Unless you can figure out what kind of Ajax requests are going on in the browser (observe the Network tab of the browser) and re-create them in Python one by one (the relevant ones at least). Tedious but it's technically possible. If the browser just requests additional data from the server and displays it, the difficulty is moderate. If the browser does elaborate calculations in some kind of client-site JS framework, things will be much harder.

Comment: I am also able to find "This item is limited to 3 per household. Just try doing this: print(requests.get('https://www.1999.co.jp/eng/10571339').text)   because it works for me.